# How to change JVectorMap Country Colors v1.2.0

Tags: colors, jvectormap

I found some code to change the country color like this:

```
colors = {};
colors['ca'] = '#A4D886';
colors['ru'] = '#FCECA2';
colors['cn'] = '#F9573B';
colors['us'] = '#87CEEB';
colors['jp'] = '#34BD0E';
colors['au'] = '#BCC7FC';
colors['kz'] = '#D4624E';
colors['de'] = '#34BD0E';
```

but where do I put it?

Here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({ map: 'world_en',});
});
</script>
```

Or

```
jQuery.fn.vectorMap = function (options) {

var defaultParams = {
  map: 'world_en',
  backgroundColor: 'black',
  color: '#f4f3f0',
  hoverColor: '#c9dfaf',
  selectedColor: '#c9dfaf',
  scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
  normalizeFunction: 'linear',
  enableZoom: true,
  showTooltip: true,
  borderColor: '#818181',
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderOpacity: 0.25,
  selectedRegions: null,
  multiSelectRegion: false,
  onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
{
    var message = 'You clicked "'
        + region
        + '" which has the code: '
        + code.toUpperCase();

    alert(message);
}
}, map = this.data('mapObject');
```

I just want to have 10 countries, US and Russia included to have different colors. I'm aware it has something to do with the 'colors' function but I can't find a source code that uses it the same way I need to.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found my own answer, for anyone wondering where you can put it, heres one

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({ map: 'world_en',
colors:{
    "us": '#4E7387'

},
series: {
  regions: 
  [{
    attribute: 'fill'
  }]
}});
});
```